Laplace operator in spherical coordinates
In my recent excercise sheet I am told to derive the laplace operator in spherical coordinates using following identity: $\underset{\mathbb{R^3}}{\int}\phi\Delta\psi d^3x = -\underset{\mathbb{R^3}}{\int}\ \nabla\phi\nabla\psi d^3x$.
As a hint my professor told me to evaluate the rhs integral in spherical coordinates which means that the nabla operators also have to be in spherical coordinates. The nabla operator therefore is given by $\nabla=\hat{e}_r\partial_r+\frac{1}{r}\hat{e}_\theta\partial_\theta+\frac{1}{rsin(\theta)}\hat{e}_\varphi\partial_\varphi$.
However when I integrated the rhs by parts I got $\underset{\mathbb{R^3}}{\int}\psi\Delta\phi d^3x - \underset{\partial\mathbb{R^3}}{\int}\psi\nabla\phi \vec{n}do$ which implies that $\underset{\partial\mathbb{R^3}}{\int}\psi\nabla\phi \vec{n}do=0$ because of the identity I mentioned at the beginning. All in all I am not sure what to do because writing out the differential operator $\nabla$ in its explicit form doesn't seem to solve the problem either because it just makes solving the integral much harder.
I would appreciate any help!

Just take $\phi$ such that $\phi(x)=0$ for $|x|>R.$

could you be more precise please

The $\nabla$ components  of functions $f$ are components of the differential form $df$ in the dual basis $(dr,d\theta, d\phi)$.
We simply need the metrics in spherical coordinates $g=\text{diag} (1,\ r^2,\ r^2 \sin^2\theta )$ for the partial derivatives
$$du \cdot dv\  =  \left( \partial_r, \partial_\theta ,\partial_\phi\right) \ u \ \cdot \  \text{diag}\left(1,\frac{1}{r^2}, \frac{1}{r^2 \ \sin^2\theta}\right) \  \cdot \ \left(\left(\partial_r, \partial_\theta ,\partial_\phi \right) \  v \ \right)^T $$
and the volume 3-form, the product of the three differentials of unit length
$$dV= dr \wedge r d\theta \wedge r \ \sin \theta \  d\phi $$
By an integration by parts for all three coordinates over $\mathbb R^3$ for smooth functions of compact support away from the boundary
$$\int\int\int dr\  d\theta \ d\phi \  \left(r^2 \sin \theta\right) \ \nabla u \ \cdot \  g^{-1} \ \cdot \ \nabla v = -\int\int\int 
dr\  d\theta \ d\phi \  \left(r^2 \sin \theta\right) \quad u \quad \left( \frac{1}{ r^2 \ \sin \theta} \ \nabla \cdot \left( ( r^2 \sin \theta)\  g^{-1} \ \cdot \ \nabla v\right) \right) $$
The general form $$\Delta = \rho^{-1} \partial_i ( \rho \ g^{ik} \partial_k)$$ is the effect of $ \rho g^{-1}$ not affected by the scalar product of forms, but becoming a middle term between the derivatives. The missing volume factor has to be reestablished factor outside, producing its inverse as a factor in $\Delta$.
Smooth functions with compact support are dense in many spaces, so the algebraic abstract form of $-\Delta$ is universal for spaces of complex scalar functions.
This is the standard definition of the Laplacian as
$$dV  \frac{1}{dV} \nabla^T \cdot \left( dV G^{-1} \nabla\right)  $$
involving the logarithmic derivatives of the volume inflation in the  the direction of the tangent and with inverse sign in the hyperplanes orthogonal.
Flowing matter is disapearing passing over the sides (div grad), by dilation in the normal direction or 'along the sides' by geometric inflation due to the nonconstant metrics.
The addtional terms in an orthogonal metrics with scale factors $h_i$ are $$\frac{1}{h_1\dots h_n} \ \left(\partial_i \frac{1}{h_i}\  h_1\dots h_n\right) \ \frac{1}{h_i} \partial_i$$ for othogonal coordinates .
By the derivation above the operator is symmetric wrt to integration by parts.
The classical derivation amounts to
$$ \left( \prod_i\,  dx_i\right)  \ \sum_i \partial_{x_i}^2 \  =  \left( \prod_i\,  dy_i\right) \sqrt{\det G}  \ \sum_i \left( \frac{\partial y_k}{ \partial x_i}\partial_{y_k}\right)^2 \ = \left(\prod_i  dy_i\right) \ \sqrt{\det G} \ \frac{1}{\sqrt{\det G}} \  \sum_{ik} \partial_{y_i}\  G^{ik} \  \partial_{y_k} $$
Any professor is using his special tool box, if he wants to go the way of classical tensor anylyis. Most of the have a good classical collection of formula of vector analysis. Gradshteyn/Rhyzik has it in the appendix eg., it can be downloaded.

thanks for your explanation but I dont think that this is the ansatz my professor wanted from us. isn't there any easier way to solve this problem?
